# how to sum all cell beside a blank cell in a row in excel?

Tags: excel, count, sum, row, blank-line

i have a table with all the contribution of the guild.
the rows consist of the member's monthly contribution to the guild.
the column represents the member's ID, m_name, jan,feb,mar,.. and so on...

I need to get the sum of all uncollected contributions for each member in that particular year.

To get the Uncollected value, I must multiply the months unpaid from the last contribution.
In my example, Columns `C:N` represents the months.
this is the code but i manually clicked each cell preceding the blank cell.
Is there an easy way to get the sum of all cells preceding the blank cell?  `=COUNTBLANK(C2:N2)*(C2+E2+E2+I2+L2)`

I have 20,000 members, doing it manually will take so much time. 
Is there another way?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Summing a blank cell will be like adding 0, so doesn't effect the result so in this case for the selected cell:

```
=sum(C2:N2)
```

For the months unpaid:

```
=countblank(C2:N2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write `=SUM(C2:N2)` in P2, then click on the small square at the bottom right of the cell and pull the cell down